# Determine if two arrays contain identical data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8, array-difference

I'm trying to compare 2 arrays and what I want to know from them is if they match and if they don't match.
So what I mean by that is if my old values matches the new values completely, for example all my old values is 100% match
for the new values down to amount that is in the array.

For example

old value

```
    array [
        Item 1,
        Item 2
    ]
```

new value

```
    array [
        Item 1,
        Item 2
    ]
```

Then that is a match, but if it's
old value

```
    array [
        Item 1,
        Item 2
    ]
```

new value

```
    array [
        Item 1,
        Item 2,
        Item 3
    ]
```

it doesn't match, because `Item 3` is now there or if it's

old value

```
    array [
        Item 1,
        Item 2
    ]
```

new value

```
    array [
        Item 1,
    ]
```

then that doesn't match because Item 2 was removed.

But with my code I'm getting this error

> Array to string conversion

and it points to this line of code `$result = array_diff($old_items, $new_items);`

Here is my code

```
    public function updateItems(Item $item, Category $category)
    {
        $old_category = $category;
        $old_items = Item::where('category_id', $old_category->id)->get()->toArray();
        
        $new_category = Category::find(request('category'));
        $new_items = Item::where('category_id', $new_category->id)->get()->toArray();

        $result = array_diff($old_items, $new_items);
        print_r($result);
        die();
    }
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error? This line> `Category::find(request('category')`?

Comment: It's this line `$result = array_diff($old_items, $new_items);`

Comment: Try `pluck`ing ids and applying array_diff to see if the error exists. `Item::where('category_id', $new_category->id)->pluck('id')->all();`

Comment: Also, `array_diff` might not be the best option for your case because it will only return items in the first array, but not in the second array. Extra/different items in the second array will be ignored. But you can make it work by applying it twice, switching old and new for the second time..

Comment: Do you want `[Item 1,Item 2]` and `[Item 2,Item 1]` to be a match or no-match? or will the items always be in the same order when they match?

Comment: They would be in the same order

Answer (score 0):

Checking if two eloquent collections are the same:

```
$old_items = Item::where('category_id', $old_category->id)->get();
$new_items = Item::where('category_id', $new_category->id)->get();

$oldDifference = $old_items->diffAssoc($new_items)->count();
$newDifference = $new_items->diffAssoc($old_items)->count();

if($oldDifference > 0 || $newDifference > 0)
  echo "not same";
```

__

Demonstrating `diffAssoc` in response to the comment:

```
$a = collect([
      "a" => 1,
      "b" => 2,
      "c" => 3,
     ]);

$b = collect([
      "a" => 1,
      "b" => 2,
      "c" => 11,
     ]);

$a->diffAssoc($b); //will yield ["a" => 1]
$b->diffAssoc($a); //will yield ["c" => 11]
```

If you want to disregard the keys, you can use `diff` instead of `diffAssoc`

Comment: That worked, but I realized one thing when I was testing, I also need to check if the stuff is the same so for example in both my old and new items they have a count of 5, but my old item might have `Item 1` and in my new item will have `Item 11` instead of `Item 1`. If that makes sense.

Comment: In that case diffAssoc will show them as different. Old difference would show item 1 as the different element and the new difference would show item 11 as the different item.

Comment: Added a small demo hoping to make it clearer.